# Argument Error (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement a like/unlike button in my rails app. Right now when I click the like button, the like gets saved in the db, but my console spits out this error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
```

I understand that this is saying that I should only be providing 1 argument and I am providing 2, but when I get rid of of the :vote argument it says that I am missing a vote param, but when when I get rid of the other argument I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"votes", :id=>"36", :vote=>{:food_id=>36, :user_id=>15}} missing required keys: [:user_id]):
```

---

This is my form partial:

```
<% unless current_user.votes.pluck(:food_id).include?(food.id) %>
    <%= button_to "Like This Food", user_votes_path({:user_id => current_user.id, :vote => { food_id: food.id, user_id: current_user.id }}), :remote => true, :method => "post" %>
<% else %>
    <% vote = food.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first %>
    <%= button_to "Unlike This Food", user_vote_path(current_user, vote), :remote => true, method: "delete", :class => "unlike-button" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @votes = Food.find(params[:food_id]).votes
  end

  def new
    @vote = Vote.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)


    if @vote.save!
      @food = @vote.food
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Liked!"}
        format.js  :locals => {:food => @food, :user_id => current_user.id} 
      end

      puts @vote.food.id
    else
      puts "No"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])

    if @vote.destroy!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Unliked!"}
        format.js
      end
    else
      puts "NOOOOOO"
    end
  end

  private

  def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(:food_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

---

```
create.js.erb

console.log('see... this is a regular javascript call.');
<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'shared/vote_form', :locals => { :food => food, :user_id => current_user.id }) %>
```

---

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home', :to => 'static_pages#home'
  get 'browse', :to => 'static_pages#browse'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  get 'static_pages/contact'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  devise_scope :user do
    delete 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    root 'devise/sessions#new'
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :votes
  end

  resources :foods do
    member do
      put "result", to: "foods#result"
    end
  end

  get 'soups', :to => 'foods#soup'
  get 'salads', :to => 'foods#salad'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: You have set wrong path for creating vote. Like this food is throwing in index action. I believe it should be create action. can you paste your route or you can see all routes with rake routes and mention the correct path in button.

Comment: I updated my post with my routes.rb file

Comment: Also, how is the path incorrect? I use :method => "post" which corresponds to the create action

Comment: Error clearly explains `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"votes", :id=>"36", :vote=>{:food_id=>36, :user_id=>15}} missing required keys: [:user_id]):`
`No routes matches action index.`

Comment: How would I change it to utilize the create action then? I'm not sure what else to do if :method => "post" is calling the index action

Comment: In the terminal view routes you have set for create. there is a quick method to look votes route like `rake routes | grep vote`.  and see the url and route helper method. If you have any confusion paste the result or you can simply  walk through.

Comment: Yeah, both the index and create action both point to the user_votes path. Post points to create and Get points to index

Comment: the comments are getting long. can you please come at discussion. so that I can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131306/discussion-between-shadow-and-harry-b).

Comment: Why do you use `user_votes_path` for Like and `user_vote_path` for Unlike? I think they should be the same and are different `method`: `button_to "Unlike This Food", user_vote_path(current_user, vote), :remote => true, method: "delete", :class => "unlike-button"` for Delete and `button_to "Unlike This Food", user_vote_path(current_user, vote), :remote => true, method: "post", :class => "unlike-button"` for Create

Comment: when I do that I get this error: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: vote):